# Implementation of lock()

Tags: c++, boost, weak-ptr

According to boost:

> To access the object, a weak_ptr can be converted to a shared_ptr using the shared_ptr constructor or the member function lock.

Again, from boost:

```
shared_ptr<T> lock() const;

//Returns: expired()? shared_ptr<T>(): shared_ptr<T>(*this).
```

As far as I understand, returning `shared_ptr<T>(*this)` means creating a new shared_ptr with reference count of 1; And this is definitely not what we want. So probably I'm not understand it right. Will someone explain? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is actually the point of shared_ptr - the copied instance will point to the same underlying data and increment the reference count for both instances.

That means that `shared_ptr<T>(*this)` will create an additional `shared_ptr` instance pointing to the same data and will increment the reference count for both `this` and the new instance.

---

It is actually more complicated in the real code, as the original `shared_ptr` data is accessed through the `weak_ptr` instance, but effectively the original `shared_ptr` data is shared at the end (with the shared reference count increased in all existing copies of the particular `shared_ptr` object).

Comment: However, the code as shown in the “Returns:” line is not thread-safe. I’m guessing that’s now how it’s *actually* implemented (my copy of the standard notes, “executed atomically”).

Comment: This means that `template<class Y> explicit shared_ptr(weak_ptr<Y> const & r);` is being called?

Comment: Yes, technically the original shared_ptr instance is accessed via the weak_ptr, but still the (updated the answer to mention that).

Comment: What do you mean by "original shared_ptr instance is accessed"?

Comment: More precisely, the original shared data (see the `shared_count( weak_count const & r, sp_nothrow_tag )` implementation in the Boost source code, which actually does the main work in this case).